# How to stop C-backspace or M-backspace from copying text?

Tags: kill-ring, deletion

Deleting a chunk of text from the cursor causes the deleted contents to be copied into the kill ring, overwriting whatever I had stored there. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: The kill ring contains the last `kill-ring-max` kills. Use C-y and repeated M-y to yank older content. [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Yanking.html#Yanking)

Comment: https://github.com/lewang/le_emacs_MRU_yank could also be useful

Answer (score 5):

If you look at what `M-backspace` calls using `C-h <M-backspace>` you see that it calls `backward-kill-word` that function simply calls `kill-word` with a negative argument. The `kill-word`  function is coded as:

```
(defun kill-word (arg)
  "Kill characters forward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (kill-region (point) (progn (forward-word arg) (point))))
```

If we write a function that does the same thing using `delete-region` instead of `kill-region` we'll get the desired result. Here is our new `delete-word` function:

```
(defun delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters forward until encountering the end of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-region (point) (progn (forward-word arg) (point))))
```

We can now write our own `backward-delete-word` using `backward-kill-work` as an example like this:

```
(defun backward-delete-word (arg)
  "Delete characters backward until encountering the beginning of a word.
With argument ARG, do this that many times."
  (interactive "p")
  (delete-word (- arg)))
```

afterwards all we need to do is bind this new function to `<M-backspace>`!

If you have any questions just let me know!